# WPF, Consuming Wdsl meta, Codedom compilation problem

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, code-generation

I am tryin to consume wdsl with a mex client. To compile it an use it without references. But i am getting compiler errors regarding "CS0246: The type or namespace name 'schema' could not be found".

I use a mexclient to import the contract

```
    MetadataExchangeClient mexClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(binding);

    mexClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
    mexClient.MaximumResolvedReferences = 1000;
    var metaSet = mexClient.GetMetadata(mexAddress, mexMode);

    WsdlImporter importer = new WsdlImporter(metaSet);
    result.ContractDescriptions = importer.ImportAllContracts();
    result.AllEndpoints = importer.ImportAllEndpoints();
```

then i generate and compile it.

```
    CodeCompileUnit unit = (CodeCompileUnit)importer.State[typeof(CodeCompileUnit)];
    ServiceContractGenerator generator = new ServiceContractGenerator(unit);

    foreach (ContractDescription contract in result.ContractDescriptions)
    {
      generator.GenerateServiceContractType(contract);
    }

    // Generate a code file for the contracts.
    CodeGeneratorOptions codeGeneratorOptions = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
    codeGeneratorOptions.BracingStyle = "C";

    // Create Compiler instance of a specified language.
    CompilerResults results;
    using (CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
    {

     CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(new string[] { 
        "System.dll", 
        "System.Data.dll", 
        "System.ServiceModel.dll", 
        "System.Runtime.Serialization.dll", 
        "System.Xml.dll", 
        "System.Xml.Linq.dll", 
        "System.Xml.Serialization.dll" });

      compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
      compilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
      compilerParameters.WarningLevel = 1;
      compilerParameters.TempFiles = new TempFileCollection("Compile", true);

      results = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(compilerParameters, generator.TargetCompileUnit);
}
```

This result in
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'schema' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When i look att the generated code i can se this unkown type

```
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("BfusTester", "1.0.0.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true,     Namespace="http://www.logica.com/BusinessForUtilities/2012/LoggerService")]
public partial class TestDS {
    
        private schema schemaField;
    
        private System.Xml.XmlElement anyField;
    
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",     Order=0)]
        public schema schema {
            get {
                return this.schemaField;
            }
            set {
                this.schemaField = value;
            }
        }
    
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order=1)]
        public System.Xml.XmlElement Any {
            get {
                return this.anyField;
            }
            set {
                this.anyField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where the line "private schema schemaField;" contains an unknown type. The method looks like this in the implementation

In interface

```
    [OperationContract]
    DataSet Test(DataSet ds);
```

And in service

```
    public DataSet Test(DataSet ds)
    {
      return new DataSet();
    }
```

It is just standard System.Data.DataSet. The interface is sadly not mine to edit.

I´m trying to tweak some options or referenced assembly on the ServiceContractGenerator and/or CodeDomProvider but without luck. It seems to me that it´s some kind of xml serialization issue.
Hope someone can give me som tips!

So a few days later!

I can see that the method with DataSet that causes the issue in CodeDom generation uses "literal" types.

```
<wsdl:operation name="Test2">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.logica.com/BusinessForUtilities/2012/LoggerService/ILoggerService/Test2" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

What i have read this tells the "ServiceContractGenerator" to look for types in a literal way. So if it´s wrong, i possibly need to tell the WsdlImporter or ServiceContractGenerator where to look for the DataSet type. But i don´t know how!

Comment: The error is due to an attribute like 'Namespace="http://www.logica.com/BusinessForUtilities/2012/LoggerService"'  Either the namespace is wrong or missing.  Without seeing the xml I cannot identify the issue better.  I find the best way of debugging xml serialization is to comment out all the properties and attributes and see if you still get the error.  Then slowly remove the comments until the error occurs.

Comment: If i remove the methods containing DataSet as parameter. And keep other methods only containing strings, ints, bools (simple types). It compiles sucesffuly. So It should be an issue with the namespace for System.DataSet

Comment: There are lots of ways of reading xml files in c#.  You can use XmlDocument (legacy xml library), XDocument (xml linq), Dataset ReadXml(), and Xml Serialization.  I'm not sure which is the best method for your application.  The Dataset method has a lot of limitations and only works for simple XML files. With complicated Xml files you end up with a lot of fractured DataTables that are useless. I can consume a WDSL XML file using combination of Xml Linq and the DataSet ReadXML() to get a dataset on simple xml files. I can write a method that takes the results of the serialization and create xml.

Comment: I can use Xml Linq and read the XML file and convert to a DataSet.  Right now I do not have enough info to determine the BEST way of going.